# prove $(F_nF_{n+3})^2+(2F_{n+1}F_{n+2})^2=F_{2n+3}^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can anyone give me some hint or start point for proof of this following identity, please?
$$(F_nF_{n+3})^2+(2F_{n+1}F_{n+2})^2=F_{2n+3}^2$$
I used a lot of ways and identities and couldn't arrive to any result!
$F_n$'s are Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a Pythagorean triple. And indeed one has
\begin{align}
&&F_{n+3}&=F_{n+2}+F_{n+1}\\
&\text{and}&F_n&=F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}\\
&\text{so that}&F_nF_{n+3}&=F_{n+2}^2-F_{n+1}^2
\end{align}
so that the left side adds to
$$
(F_{n+2}^2+F_{n+1}^2)^2.
$$
Now use the index doubling identities 
\begin{align}
F_{2n}&=F_n(F_{n+1}+F_{n-1})=F_{n+1}^2-F_{n-1}^2,\\
F_{2n+1}&=F_{n+1}^2+F_n^2,
\end{align}
of the Fibonacci sequence.